# Django: How can I tell if a certain quality of all objects in a RelatedManager is the same?

Tags: python, django

Let's say I have a ManyToManyField, from Swallow -=> Coconut.

Also, let's say that Coconut has a boolean field called "Young."

For a given swallow, how can I tell if all its coconuts are young?

(What I'm really looking for is not so much the ability to tell whether the swallow's coconuts are young, but a way to tell whether there is a divergent value among the items in a queryset.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I figured it out.  I need:

```
swallow.coconuts.aggregate(test=Variance('young'))
```

If that is 0, I know that they are all the same.

Comment: That works for numerical and boolean fields, but not for text fields (e.g. if you want to check if all coconuts have the color "brown").

Answer (score 0):

```
if there is no `coconut` for a `swallow` that is `not young`
then all `coconuts` are `young`
```

EDIT:

as far as I know, there is no queryset method that can do that, but you can make your own, like:

```
# property_values is a dictionary : {prop1:val1, prop2:val2,...}
# you can check for multiple properties

def is_same_property_value(related_manager, property_values)
    return related_manager.filter(~Q(**property_values)).count() == 0


res = is_same_property_value(swallow.coconuts_set, {'young':true})
```

Comment: But again, I don't want it to work only for 'young' or for booleans for that matter.  I just want to find out, for a given relatedmanager, if all of the related objects have the same value for a given field.